# Javascript loop and final alert, FOR or WHILE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Novice in programming, this is my practice the code, I can't figure out how to code my concept and I am not sure if I need to use `for` or `while` for the following requirement:

> After 3 or 5 times the user fails to input something in the prompt box, then a final alert shows up telling something like "No more Opportunities!" and then turns the `div` background grey color.

Any help will be welcome to help me improve.

JS

```
var mObjt = {
    userInput: "",

    setInput: function(){
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = mObjt.userInput;
    },

    conRequest: function(){
        if(mObjt.userInput != ""){
            mObjt.setInput();
        } else {
            alert("There is no input!");
            mObjt.popRequest();
        }
    },

    popRequest: function(){ 
        mObjt.userInput = prompt("Enter a word:");
        mObjt.conRequest();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:200px; height:30px; border:1px solid;"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="mObjt.popRequest()">Add Property</button>
```

Comment: The bold words is what I want.

Comment: You can use either for or while loop, depending on your preferences. But I suggest you read first how loops work before asking this kind of question

Comment: sot any ideas, I want the prompt box to give the user 5 opportunities, and he fails then an alert and then the  DIV turning grey.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use any type of loop for that. Keep a counter variable. Every time the user fails, increase the counter. When the counter gets to 5, do whatever needs to be done.

```
var failCount = 0;

function handleInput() {
  // This is a totally fake example just to show you want to do
  if(input) {
    // Input valid, yay
  } else {
    // Input invalid
    failCount++;
    if(failCount >= 5) {
      // Disable your stuff
      alert('Oh no, input failed: you have no more remaining attempts');
    } else {
      alert('Oh no, input failed');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming the prompt should only come up once per click of the button. It sounds like he wants the prompt to continue up to 5 times after the click if a word isn't provided, which would require a loop.